# Validating AuthToken from sign in with apple JS on .net Backend

Tags: .net, .net-core, oauth-2.0, cng, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to implement Sign in with apple on our Web App, It works on AppleTV and IOS but the same flow doesn't seem to work with the token from Apple JS and I get `INVALID_CLIENT`.

It seems it needs a few extra steps so I added the KID and such and now I'm stuck on `INVALID_GRANT` (which is better according to what I understand at least the client is Ok).

From the `Js` side I do the following : (The flow seems correct with appropriate response in `AppleIDSignInOnSuccess`)

```js
AppleID.auth.init({  
                 clientId: 'com.#########.weblogin',//service Id created   
                  scope: 'name email',  
                  state: state,  
                  redirectURI: location.href,  
                  usePopup: true //or false defaults to false  
              }); 



document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnSuccess', (data) => {  
            //handle successful response  
            var deviceKey = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)deviceKey\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");  
            requestLogin({  
                AppleToken: data.detail.authorization.id_token,  
                AppleAuthorizationCode: btoa(data.detail.authorization.code),//our api requires base64urlsafe strings to be symetric with native apps
                FirstName: data.detail.user?.firstName,  
                LastName: data.detail.user?.LastName,  
                DeviceKey:  deviceKey  
            });  
        });
```

To be noted though that unlike the documentation [state] isn't returned, it might not be necessary in case of popup but that could be a sign that something is wrong.

Now I handle the AuthorizationCode with my `.NET` backend.

```
Hclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Microsoft ASP.NET Core OpenIdConnect handler");  

var datas = new Dictionary<string, string="">()  
                        {  
                            { "client_id" , request.DeviceKey.StartsWith("WEB_") ? "com.########.weblogin" : "com.########.app" }, //use the serviceId and not the main appId for web  
                            { "code" , request.AppleAuthorizationCode.FromBase64UrlSafe().FromUtf8Bytes() },  
                            { "grant_type" , "authorization_code" },  
                            { "redirect_uri", "https://login.#######.com/signin-apple" },  
                            {"client_secret",request.DeviceKey.StartsWith("WEB_") ? TokenGenerator2.CreateNewToken() : TokenGenerator.CreateNewToken() }//generate the client_secret differently for web  
                        };  
var formdata = new FormUrlEncodedContent(datas);  

using (HttpResponseMessage res = Hclient.PostAsync("https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token",formdata ).Result)
```

This is the call that respond "INVALID_GRANT". And this Is how I generate my jwt token client_secret.

```
public static class TokenGenerator2  
        {  
            public static string CreateNewToken()  
            {  
                const string iss = "7#######G"; // team ID  
                const string aud = "https://appleid.apple.com";  
                const string sub = "com.#######.weblogin"; // service Id  
                const string keyId =  "G######W";//key Idassociated with the p8 file  

                const string privateKey = "MIGT####...#####"; // contents of AuthKey_[keyId].p8 file  



                var d = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5);//I was worried the date time was the issue so I took a laaaaarge one ...  


                var cngKey = CngKey.Import(  
                  Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey),  
                  CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);  


                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();  


                var securityKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(new ECDsaCng(cngKey) { KeySize = 256 , HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256});  


                securityKey.KeyId = keyId;  
                var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256);  


                return  handler.CreateEncodedJwt(iss, aud, new ClaimsIdentity(new List { new Claim("sub", sub) }),d, expires: d.AddMonths(3),d, signingCredentials: signingCredentials);  

            }  

        }
```

For reference this is how I create it for the native apps (the flow that do work)

```
  public static class TokenGenerator  
        {  
            public static string CreateNewToken()  
            {  
                const string iss = "7#######G"; // your account's team ID found in the dev portal  
                const string aud = "https://appleid.apple.com";  
                const string sub = "com.######.app";   
                const string privateKey = "MIGTAg###...####"; // contents of .p8 file  


                var cngKey = CngKey.Import(  
                  Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey),  
                  CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);  
                var d = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5);  


                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();  
                var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(  
                    issuer: iss,  
                    audience: aud,  
                    subject: new ClaimsIdentity(new List { new Claim("sub", sub) }),  
                    expires: d.AddMonths(3), // expiry can be a maximum of 6 months  
                    issuedAt: d,  
                    notBefore: d,  
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(  
                      new ECDsaSecurityKey(new ECDsaCng(cngKey)), SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256));  


                return handler.WriteToken(token);  
            }  


        }
```

Comment: I'm working on Sign in with Apple using the Javascript SDK. I'm trying to use the pop-up flow to login but it seems like the `AppleIDSignInOnSuccess` is never fired when the login process is completed. Have you done some configuration to make that work ? Thanks.

Comment: Appart from creating a Service Identifier, none.  
Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles => Identifiers   and then + sign

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've got some detail from Apple developper assistance. The redirect uri should be on the same domain has the uri that open the pop-up. It works now.

Comment: Same subdomain aswell ?      because I call the js from    mydomain.com and then the redirect uri is login.mydomain.com .. could be my issue

Comment: Yes, same for the subdomain. Feel free to tell me if it worked. In this case, I will create a answer for this topic.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @obit. Ran into the same problem testing on localhost. The `redirect-uri` must specify the same as fully qualified domain name (including subdomain) as the page where the popup is triggered. Using something like https://ngrok.com/ and specifying the correct domain for the relevant service ID solved the problem.

Would be nice if the Apple JS SDK didn't fail silently in this particular case and waste my development time :shrug: